# fpdf output can't load into browser.

Tags: php, jquery, fpdf

i am trying to create and download pdf from html table using fpdf in my wordpress plugin.
output shows similar to the following lines in console instead of open pdf to my browser.

```
%PDF-1.4
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/Resources 2 0 R
/Group <</Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB>>
/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 502>>
stream
x����o�0���+�q����&}�Z���N�f�[L%ai������E����gߙ��A�������@�#j
�"a����W�{
```

i have sent data to actionpdf.php using jQuery. 
here is my jquery script to send html table to actionpdf.php

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#btnPdf').on('click',function(){

                $.post('".plugins_url('',__FILE__)."/html-to-fpdf/actionpdf.php');

            });
        });
    </script>
```

and here is my action pdf.php-

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4'); //with page settings
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!',1);
$pdf->Cell(60,10,'Powered by FPDF.',0,1,'C');
$pdf->Output('sara.pdf', 'D'); //force download file
exit;
?>
```

what i am doing wrong? i am stuck on that.any helps are welcome.

Comment: Did you find the answer? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to set the content-type to "application/pdf" to make it working as expected.

Comment: header('Content-type: application/pdf'); i already tried this before.didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `contentType` to `'application/pdf'` in the ajax call

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/